# Inconsistent word and character boundaries in ICU

Tags: unicode, unicode-string

I'm using ICU's break iterators for both characters and words as described in [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis). I expect the output of character break iterator stops more frequently and the break-points be a superset of that of word break iterator. For instance, if I pass `abc`, I get `a`, `b`, and `c` from character break iterator while I get `abc` from word break iterator.

Now, I have a Thai string as `ด้าน้ำ`. The problem is that the behavior of these two break iterators are inconsistent. Given the length of the above string is 6 in Unicode, I get these results from ICU 61.1 on MacOS:

```
Word boundaries:
[0, 5)
[5, 6)
Character boundaries:
[0, 2)
[2, 3)
[3, 6)
```

As you can see, character break operator breaks the word in `[3, 6)` (which seems correct), while word break operator breaks it in `[5, 6)`. Here's a small Python3 code which uses PyICU to repro the issue:

```py
import PyICU

def wordBreakIterator():
    return PyICU.BreakIterator.createWordInstance(PyICU.Locale("th"))

def charBreakIterator():
    return PyICU.BreakIterator.createCharacterInstance(PyICU.Locale("th"))

def printBoundaries(txt, bi):
    bi.setText(txt)
    start = bi.first()
    try:
        while True:
            end = next(bi)
            print("[{}, {})".format(start, end))
            start = end
    except StopIteration:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = u'ด้าน้ำ'

    print("Word boundaries:")
    printBoundaries(text, wordBreakIterator())

    print("Character boundaries:")
    printBoundaries(text, charBreakIterator())
```

Comment: @Javad, what have you concluded?

Comment: @DavidNogueira I reported it as a bug to ICU developers. It's been accepted and have been remained in this state for a while. Feel free to ping it: https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/ICU-13690

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing the rules in [Technical Report #29](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/) which defines how you determine user perceived character (aka grapheme cluster), word, and sentence boundaries.  The rule sets do not build on each other, instead being defined completely independently of each other.  For example that means words are **not** defined by iterating over the grapheme clusters, but separately over the underlying codepoints.  Each ruleset also has its own separate set of data tables.  As a result there will be cases where they don't match as you found.

Applying the current Unicode 15.1 rules and data tables, the character spans are unchanged and the word spans are:

```
(0, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 5)
(5, 6)
```

At the bottom notes of the [word boundary rules](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundary_Rules) it says:

> For Thai, Lao, Khmer, Myanmar, and other scripts that do not typically use spaces between words, a good implementation should not depend on the default word boundary specification.

You will need to do that!